# Angular 2 Transclusion / ng-content, communicate dependencies

Tags: angular

Given the example below, is there a way to communicate (through code, not documentation) to consumers of the 'card' component that a 'card-header', content and 'card-footer' should be included?

Example Component:

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'card',
    templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
})
export class CardComponent {
}
```

Example HTML (card.component.html):

```ts
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <ng-content select="card-header"></ng-content>
  </div>

  <ng-content></ng-content>

  <div class="card-footer">
    <ng-content select="card-footer"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for passed content and throw exceptions.
There is currently no way to notify the user at development time.

```dart
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" #header>
    <ng-content select="card-header"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div #body>    
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </body>
  <div class="card-footer" #footer>
    <ng-content select="card-footer"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

```dart
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'card',
    templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
})
export class CardComponent {
  @ContentChildren('header') header:ElementRef;
  @ContentChildren('body') body:ElementRef;
  @ContentChildren('footer') header:ElementRef;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if(!this.header.toArray().length) {
      throw 'No content was provided that matches ".card-header".';
    }
    if(!this.body.toArray().length) {
      throw 'No body content was provided.';
    }
    if(!this.footer.toArray().length) {
      throw 'No content was provided that matches ".card-footer".';
    }
  }
}
```

There is some language service work in progress that might eventuallyprovide hints for `<ng-content>` elements where not children were passed that match their selectors.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to conditionally show the projected HTML inside `CardComponent`. In this case you can use `*ngIf`. For example, you can declare a boolean variable (or an `@Input` param) in your `CardComponent`:

```ts
showFooter: boolean=false;
```

Then in the template you do this:

```ts
  <div *ngIf="showFooter">
    <ng-content select="card-footer"></ng-content>
  </div>
```

The parent of the `CardComponent` would have the following in its template:

```ts
  <card>
    <div class="card-header" ><i>Card got this header from parent</i></div>
    <div class="card-footer"><i>Card got this footer from parent</i></div>
  </card>
```

If `showFooter` is `false`, the `CardComponent` won't render the footer.

If you want to control the projected content in the parent of `CardComponent`, implement the similar logic in the parent.